# Muktza not being directly handled (i.e. in a backpack)?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

If say I'm walking in an area with an eiruv (that I hold of etc.), and it becomes Shabbos and I have a muktza object on me, if I put it in a backpack so that I'm not actually touching it, is it still considered muktza?

Comment: "is it still considered muktza" Do you mean "is it still forbidden to move"? I find it highly unlikely that something's muktza status would change based on its location relative to you and your backpack, but if that's what you are asking please [edit] to indicate why you think that may be the case.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Your case might be exceptional if he is already holding the muktzeh item when shabbos starts

Answer (score 2):

Muktza is not technically (at least primarily) an issue of touching but of *moving*. However, there are certain scenarios where indirect moving (*tiltul min hatzad*) is permitted. (See, e.g. http://www.dinonline.org/2011/05/30/tiltul-min-hatzad/ )

Comment: But does this qualify as tiltul min hatzad?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 88:17](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0166_L5) where he mentions (just BTW) that once one is holding Muktza (for whatever reason) then one can continue holding until one finds a good place to put it down.

So it would seem that if you notice the Muktza once it becomes Shabbat, you can continue carrying it until you find a place you're comfortable putting it down, or shaking it out of a pocket, as the case may be.

> **סעיף יז:'** 
>   כָּל דָּבָר מְטֻנָּף, כְּגוֹן רְעִי וְקִיא צוֹאָה, בֵּין שֶׁל אָדָם בֵּין שֶׁל תַּרְנְגוֹלִים, אִם הֵם בְּבַיִת אוֹ בֶּחָצֵר שֶׁיּוֹשְׁבִים שָׁם בְּנֵי אָדָם, מֻתָּר לְהוֹצִיאָם לָאַשְׁפָּה. וּכְשֶׁמּוֹצִיא גְּרָף שֶׁל רְעִי אוֹ עָבִיט שֶׁל מֵי רַגְלַיִם, **כָּל זְמַן שֶׁהַכְּלִי עֲדַיִן בְּיָדוֹ, מֻתָּר לְהַחְזִירוֹ, כְּדִין כָּל מֻקְצֶה שֶׁבְּעוֹדוֹ בְּיָדוֹ, מֻתָּר לְטַלְטְלוֹ לְהַנִּיחוֹ בְּמָּקוֹם שֶׁיִּרְצֶה.** אֲבָל לְאַחַר שֶׁהִנִּיחוֹ מִיָּדוֹ, אָסוּר לְטַלְטְלוֹ, מִשּׁוּם דְּמָאִיס טְפֵי (וְגָרַע מִשְׁאָר מֻקְצֶה מֵחֲמַת מִאוּס). וְאַךְ כְּשֶׁצְּרִיכִין לוֹ מִשּׁוּם כְּבוֹד הַבְּרִיּוֹת, מֻתָּר לְהַחְזִירוֹ (ש"ח). וְכֵן אִם יָכוֹל לָתֵת בְּתוֹכוֹ מַיִם, שֶׁיִּהְיוּ רְאוּיִין לִשְׁתִּיַּת בְּהֵמָה, יָכוֹל לְהַחְזִירוֹ כָּךְ. ‏