# Carrying items on keychains Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, eruv-chatzerot

One may generally not transport muktzeh on Shabbos, [even within an eiruv](http://www.rabbibelovski.co.uk/2005/06/what-is-permitted-inside-eruv.html). However, if the carrying is indirect, and [not for the purpose](http://dinonline.org/2011/05/30/tiltul-min-hatzad/) of bringing the muktzeh, must one be makpid to ensure before Shabbos that it does not happen? For example, would one need to remove a flashlight or multi-tool from a keychain before carrying it in a purse?

Highly related, but not quite identical: [Muktza not being directly handled (i.e. in a backpack)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/muktza-not-being-directly-handled-i-e-in-a-backpack)

Comment: Also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/keychain-with-muktzeh